# Scala: Implicit parameters should "without a prefix"?

Tags: scala

According to http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/implicit-parameters.html, it says

> The actual arguments that are eligible to be passed to an implicit parameter fall into two categories:
>
> - First, eligible are all identifiers x that can be accessed at the point of the method call without a prefix and that denote an implicit definition or an implicit parameter

Here confuses me is that , what is meaning of "without a prefix"?

Comment: **without a prefix** means the variable can be found directly in the context ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

```
  implicit val i = "hello"                        //> i  : String = hello

  object Inner {
     implicit val j = "goodbye"
  }

  def foo(implicit s: String) = println(s)   

  foo("explicit")                               //> explicit
  foo(Inner.j)                                  //> goodbye
  foo                                           //> hello
```

`i` is visible at the point of calling `foo()` so can be considered as an implicit parameter. `j` is a member of the `Inner` object, so is not accessible without a prefix, i.e. `Inner.j`, so can only be passed explicitly. To access `j` without a prefix, so that it is eligible to be an implicit parameter, we'd have to import it:

```
  object Inner {
     implicit val j = "goodbye"
  }

  def foo(implicit s: String) = println(s)

  import Inner._

  foo                                           //> goodbye
```